# Product Manifold: Tangent Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry

**Problem**

Given a product manifold.

> How to prove that its tangent spaces split into direct sums:
>   $$T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\cong T_pM\oplus T_qN$$

**Attempts**

One could try the geometric perspective:
$$\Phi:T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\to T_pM\oplus T_qN:[(\alpha,\beta)]\mapsto([\alpha],[\beta])$$
$$\Psi:T_pM\oplus T_qN\to T_{(p,q)}(M\times N):([\alpha],[\beta])\mapsto[(\alpha,\beta)]$$
Then bijectivity becomes pretty easy but linearity quite nasty.

*(Besides it is well-defined.)*

One could also try the algebraic perspective:
$$\Phi:T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\to T_pM\oplus T_qN:\delta\mapsto(d_{(p,q)}\pi_M\delta,d_{(p,q)}\pi_N\delta)$$
Then linearity becomes evident but bijectivity becomes pain.

*(Besides there's an explicit but ugly inverse.)*

Is there maybe some nice trick??

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413766/tangent-space-of-product-manifold?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take "coordinate" projections $\pi_X,\pi_Y$ from $M \times N$ to $M$ and $N$. Let $(p,q) \in M \times N$, so that you have a map $F : T_{(p,q)}(M \times N) \to T_p M \times T_q  N$ sending $v$ to $\left(d(\pi_X)_{(p,q)}(v), d(\pi_Y)_{(p,q)}(v) \right)$. This map is a linear map that is an isomorphism with inverse given by the linear map $g : T_p M \times T_q N \to T_{(p,q)} (M \times N)$ that sends $(v,w)$ to $d(s_M)_p(v) +d(s_N)_q(w)$ where $s_M : M\to M\times N$ sends $M$ to $M \times \{q\}$ and where $s_N$...

Comment: Great, thanks. :)

Comment: I know why $F\circ g=$id. But why $g\circ F=$id?

Comment: It is really easy to see that this function $g$ is a isomorphism without use of the function $\Phi$ :-)

Comment: @TiWen the composition $g\circ F$ is not the identity (as far as I can see). However, since $F\circ g$ is the identity, $g$ is injective and $F$ is surjective. Using either of these facts, since domain and range have the same dimension and both $F$ and $g$ are linear (as they are defined in terms of derivatives), they both are isomorphisms.

Comment: @Jānis Lazovskis I appreciate your hint about dimension, since I could not work out $g\circ F = id$ either.

However, as far as I am concerned, $g\circ F$ should be identity, because $g$ is a right inverse of $F$, and $F$ is invertible by the dimension argument.