# Maps between tangent space of product manifold and sum of tangent spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to prove that
$$T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\cong T_pM\oplus T_qN$$

We define:
$$\Phi:T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\to T_pM\oplus T_qN:v\mapsto(d_{(p,q)}\pi_M v,d_{(p,q)}\pi_N v)$$
and
$$\Psi:T_pM\oplus T_qN\to T_{(p,q)}(M\times N), (v,w)\mapsto d(\iota_M)_p(v) +d(\iota_N)_q(w),$$
 where $\iota_M : M\to M\times N$ sends $M$ to $M \times \{q\}$ and where $\iota_N : N\to M\times N$ sends $N$ to $N\times \{q\}$

I have trouble in showing that $\Psi \circ \Phi=\text{Id}$. Let $f$ be a smooth function on $M\times N$. Compute

\begin{align*}
\Psi \circ \Phi(v)f  
&= \Psi (d_{(p,q)}\pi_M v,d_{(p,q)}\pi_N v)f \\
&=  \big(d_{(p,q)}(\iota_M \circ \pi_M) v,d_{(p,q)}(\iota \circ \pi_N) v \big)f \\
&= v(f\circ \iota_M \circ \pi_M )+v(f \circ \iota_N \circ \pi_N) \\
&= v(f\circ \iota_M \circ \pi_M + f \circ \iota_N \circ \pi_N)
\end{align*}

But I don't know why the last term is equal to $v(f)$. I looked at many solutions to this problem on stackexchange([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413766/tangent-space-of-product-manifold?rq=1), for example), but they seem to take this part for granted.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to see that $\Phi \circ \Psi = \operatorname{Id}$. Then $\Psi$ is injective so you have an isomorphism for dimensional reasons.

To see this take $v \in T_pM, w \in T_qN$, then

\begin{align}
 \Phi\circ\Psi(v,w) & = \Phi\left(d(\iota_M)_pv + d(\iota_N)_qw\right)\\
& = \left(d(\pi_M)_{(p,q)}\left(d(\iota_M)_pv + d(\iota_N)_qw\right), d(\pi_N)_{(p,q)}\left(d(\iota_M)_pv + d(\iota_N)_qw\right)  \right) \\
&= \left(d(\pi_M \circ \iota_M)_pv + d(\pi_M \circ \iota_N)_qw, d(\pi_N\circ\iota_M)_pv + d(\pi_N \circ \iota_N)_qw \right)
\end{align}

Now $\pi_M \circ \iota_M$ and $\pi_N \circ \iota_N$ are the identity on $M$ and $N$ respectively so the pushforwards with respect to these maps are also the identity. Since $\pi_M \circ \iota_N$ and $\pi_N \circ \iota_M$ are constant maps, their corresponding pushforwards are zero.