# Show that for smooth manifolds $X$ and $Y$, $T[X \times Y]_{(x, y)} = TX_x \times TY_y$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-verification, differential-topology, proof-explanation

> Show that for smooth manifolds $X$ and $Y$, $T[X \times Y]_{(x, y)} = TX_x \times TY_y$

Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m$. Then $X \times Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k+l}$ is a smooth manifold of $\text{dim} = k+l$

Choose parameterizations $\phi : U \to \phi[U]$ and $\psi : V \to \psi[V]$, of neighbourhoods $\phi[U]$ of $x \in X$ and $\psi[V]$ of $y \in Y$, and suppose $\phi(u) = x$ and $\psi(v) = y$.

Then $\phi \times \psi : U \times V \to \phi[U] \times \psi[V]$ defined by $\phi \times \psi(u, v) = (\psi(u), \psi(v))$ is a local parameterization of $X \times Y$ around $(x, y)$.

Now $$T[X \times Y]_{(x, y)} = d( \phi \times \psi)_{(u, v)}\left[\mathbb{R}^{k+l}\right] = d\left((u, v) \mapsto (\phi(u), \psi(v))\right)_{(u, v)}[\mathbb{R}^{k+l}]$$

The next step would be to look at the Jacobian of the RHS above, but the thing is that that the tangent space is the image $d( \phi \times \psi)_{(u, v)}\left[\mathbb{R}^{k+l}\right]$

$$T[X \times Y]_{(x, y)} = \text{Im}\left( 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    d\phi_u & 0 \\
    0 & d\psi_u
  \end{bmatrix} \right)
$$

From the above how could I complete the proof?

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense. If $A$ is an $m\times k$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times\ell$ matrix, what is the *image* of the linear map $$\begin{bmatrix} A & O \\  O& B\end{bmatrix}?$$ Hint: Your matrix $A$ has rank $k$ and has image $V\subset\Bbb R^m$, and your matrix $B$ has rank $\ell$ and has image $W\subset\Bbb R^n$. Your answer needs to be a $(k+\ell)$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^m\times\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413766/tangent-space-of-product-manifold) can help

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I think I understand everything above now $$\text{Im}\left( 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A & 0 \\
    0 & B
  \end{bmatrix} \right)
$$ as you say would be a $(k+l)$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't see how from that I could conclude that $T[X \times Y]_{(x, y)} = TX_x \times TY_y$